# Класс БД. Определить метод

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть подключение к БД, не могу понять смысл некоторых методов, на сайте developer.android.com не нашел.

Скажите, пожалуйста, зачем нужен метод public SQLiteDatabase getDb()? Это что-то типа конструктора?

```
  package ru.mitasov.mnemotehnika;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//Путь к папке с базами на устройстве
public static String DB_PATH;
//Имя файла с базой
public static String DB_NAME;
public SQLiteDatabase database;
public final Context context;

public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
    return database;
}

public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
    super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
    this.context = context;
    //Составим полный путь к базам для вашего приложения
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
    DB_NAME = databaseName;
    openDataBase();
}

//Создаст базу, если она не создана
public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
            throw new Error("Error copying database!");
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
    }
}
//Проверка существования базы данных
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
    try {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
    }
    //Андроид не любит утечки ресурсов, все должно закрываться
    if (checkDb != null) {
        checkDb.close();
    }
    return checkDb != null;
}
//Метод копирования базы
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    // Открываем поток для чтения из уже созданной нами БД
    //источник в assets
    InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Путь к уже созданной пустой базе в андроиде
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    // Теперь создадим поток для записи в эту БД побайтно
    OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    // Собственно, копирование
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    // Мы будем хорошими мальчиками (девочками) и закроем потоки
    localDbStream.close();
    externalDbStream.close();

}

public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    if (database == null) {
        createDataBase();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    return database;
}
@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        database.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

А в какой среде разрабатываете?
Например, в `Android studio` можно нажать `CTRL+Q` (установив курсор на интересующий метод) и откроются доки.
В `Eclipse`, `F2` по-моему.
А еще, вот посмотреть можно [тут](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html). И метод `getDb`, видимо, самописный. Возвращает объект  класса `SQLiteOpenHelper`.